# UITest How to get reusable view with identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a custom view which contains, lets say, a `textfield` like the following way seen in the picture. This view is used more than one time in the same controller. How to get the textfield for `UITesting` without using placeholder text?

[image]

Comment: Your tags arn't clear to me. The "coded-ui-tests" tag is used to denote your question is about MS Visual Studio coded ui tests. There is also the "xcode" tag, used for asking questions about Apple's IDE. Please add some more info to your question, it will greatly improve your chances to get a quality answer from someone.

Comment: @PixelPlex Yes i have updated tag according to your suggestion thanks